# Exported animations missing keyframes?

Tags: animation

So I'm exporting an animation. The devs on my team want a delay/idle at the end, so I simply copied the keyframes of the last frame of the animation.[image]

But when exported its doesn't show up?????????? I'm using the default fbx export with no changes at all to the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the "simplify" in the export options(fbx) seems to remove the keyframes. Exported the mesh with that option turn off, exports with the keyframes correctly.